# What trick does Java use to avoid spaces in >>?

Tags: java, c++, templates, generics, grammar

In the Java Generic Book, while contrasting the difference between C++ Templates and Java Generic says:

> In C++, a problem arises because >>
>   without the space denotes the
>   right-shift  operator.  Java fixes the
>   problem by a trick in the grammar.)

What is this trick?

Comment: C++0x and Visual C++ 2010 also have this problem sorted out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Angle_bracket

Comment: It’s not really related to the question, but I like the trick Scala uses to avoid this problem: `List[List[String]]` instead of `List<List<String>>`. Problem solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually being fixed in C++ in the next version. There really isn't much of  a trick; if you encounter >> while in the process of parsing a generic or template where instead you expected >, then you already have enough information to generate an error message. And, if you have enough information to generate an error message, you also have enough information to interpret >> as two separate tokens: > followed by >.

Comment: This is incorrect in the case of C++, since `A<1<<b>>c>` is a valid generic type with a single ordinal parameter, `1<<b>>c`.

Comment: @Marcelo, but there is no error in that case, and so it is not necessary to expand >> or <<... so I don't see how what I have said is incorrect.

Answer (score 9):

The OpenJDK javac parser, `JavacParser`, massages the lexer tokens `GTGTGTEQ` (`>>>=`), `GTGTEQ`, `GTEQ`, `GTGTGT` (`>>>`) and `GTGT` into the token with one less '`>`' character when parsing type arguments.

Here is a snippet of the magic from `JavacParser#typeArguments()`:

```
    switch (S.token()) {
    case GTGTGTEQ:
        S.token(GTGTEQ);
        break;
    case GTGTEQ:
        S.token(GTEQ);
        break;
    case GTEQ:
        S.token(EQ);
        break;
    case GTGTGT:
        S.token(GTGT);
        break;
    case GTGT:
        S.token(GT);
        break;
    default:
        accept(GT);
        break;
    }
```

One can clearly see that it is indeed a trick, and it's in the grammar :)

Comment: How is this not the accepted answer? It is the only one with actually answers the question.

Answer (score 5):

It's a simple parser/lexer hack. The lexical analyser normally recognises the pair `>>` as a single token. However, when in the middle of parsing a generic type, the parser tells the lexer not to recognise `>>`.

Historically, C++ didn't do this for the sake of implementation simplicity, but it can (and will) be fixed using the same trick.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really a trick, they just defined the grammar such that a right shift token is synonymous with with two right angle brackets (thus allowing that token to close a template).  You can still create ambiguities that have to be resolved with parentheses, but unambiguous sequences are parsed without developer intervention.  This is also done in C++0x.

Answer (score 1):

[The Java Language Specification, Third Edition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/syntax.html#18.1) shows the full grammar, both shift operators are listed in the `InfixOp` production, there is no (obvious) trick. to determine which operation >, >> or  >>> is intented, will be decided by the scanner using a [lookahead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookahead) technique.

Comment: yes, but section 3.2 actually required ">>" to be parsed into one token, no matter what. a little inconsistency there.