# Does any language use "=/=" for denoting the not-equal operator

Tags: programming-languages, operators

1. Does any programming language use `=/=` for not-equal?
2. Are there any lexical difficulties for scanners to recognize such an operator? Or was it the case historically?

[Note: this is NOT a homework question. I'm just curious.]

Comment: I can't imagine parsing `<>` is less difficult than parsing `=/=`, except for the 50% increase in length.

Comment: not a bad idea, I mean != doesn't look any better than =/=

Comment: Are you thinking that =/= is a better visual approximation for ≠ (0x2260)? Interesting idea.

Comment: Haskell uses `/=` as the not equal operator.

Comment: @Khnle: Except for `!` usually means *not* so `!=` actually reads as "not equals."  `=/=` doesn't decompose as nicely.  Also on regular querty keyboards `/` is on the lower right corner of the keyboard and kind of a pain to get to when you type.

Comment: @Bob No I don't really judge it or propose it. I'm just curios if it exists (which turned out to be the case for Erlang's exact not-equal).

Comment: @R0MANARMY you have a good point about the typing difficulty.

Comment: @R0MANARMY good points, you convinced me.

Comment: @ROMANARMY: `!` only "usually" means `not` if your whole computing experience is dominated by the C infestation.

Comment: @JUST MY correct OPINION: valid point

Comment: Just me being a cranky old codger is all.  :)

Comment: abhin4v: So does Common Lisp.

Comment: Yuck.  I sure hope no language does it that way.  Looks like "assignment divided by assignment".  :-O

Comment: so does fortran too ( /= or .ne.)

Comment: @ROMANARMY I have a qwerty keyboard and / is on 7... you meant: on an english (or alike) qwerty keyboard...

Comment: @MvanGeest:  `<>` is generally read as "greater or less than", so it's not as intuitive for sets without strong ordering, for example the complex numbers.  Some sort of negation sign coupled with an equality operator makes more sense in general, like C's `!=`.

Comment: @David Thornley: I was just answering the second question. You're right.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Erlang uses it to denote [exactly not equal to](https://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#term-comparisons).

Also generally there shouldn't be any difficulties for scanners to recognize such a token (proof by example: Erlang ;-)

Answer (score 12):

In Erlang `=/=`, [as noted by Bytecode Ninja](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062428/does-any-language-use-for-denoting-the-not-equal-operator/3062491#3062491) means "exactly not equal to".  The notation of Erlang is strongly influenced by Prolog so it should come as no surprise that [Prolog uses that operator too](http://boklm.eu/prolog/page_14.html#141).  There are several languages which make defining operators trivial.  Haskell would be one such.  `=/=` isn't defined in the Haskell standard, but defining it would be trivial:

```
(=/=) x y = ....
```

This could then be used in function call-like syntax:

```
(=/=) 5 6
```

Or as an inline operator:

```
5 =/= 6
```

The semantics would depend on the implementation, of course.

I think that Common Lisp <s>weenies</s> users could write some kind of reader macro that used that sequence too, but I'm not positive.

Comment: Thanks for the Prolog link. I can see the similarity between Erlang's operators and Prolog.

Comment: The better you know either language, the more familiar the other will look (but **not** behave!).

Comment: No reason to write a reader macro (mainly because that would be a right pain). Easier to just do (defun =/= (&rest args) (apply #'/= args))

Comment: I just figured a reader macro was closest in conception to an "operator" in Common Lisp.

Answer (score 2):

1. Not one of the mainstream ones. One could easily create such a language, however.

   - (As others have mentioned, Erlang and a few other languages do have it already)
2. Nope. Unless you have a really weird language, there's nothing special about this operator in terms of lexical analysis.

By the way, Java has:

- `>` (greater than)
- `>>` (signed right shift)
- `>>=` (signed right shift compound assignment)
- `>>>` (unsigned right shift)
- `>>>=` (unsigned right shift compound assignment)
- `>` (closing generic type parameter, nestable)

  - `>>`, `>>>`, `>>>>`, ...

and they all work just fine.

#### Related question

- [What trick does Java use to avoid spaces in >> ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808324/what-trick-does-java-use-to-avoid-spaces-in)

Comment: RE: 2. I think I got what you mean by "really weird language": some syntax that would make it ambiguous to recognize =/=, e.g. allowing = or / as literals or something. Has to be quite weird. And thanks for the Java example.

Comment: IIRC, that specific java example introduces ambiguity.  For example, `LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>>`.  The trailing `>>` could either be two nested closing generics, or the right shift operator.  I don't know how it figures this out, but I'm pretty sure it's not context free.  C++ doesn't allow this (you have to put a space between the two closing template thingies).

Comment: @rmeador: It works just fine in Java; the parser has a special rule to allow it without space. I'll pull up the reference. Looking for it...

Comment: I know it works fine.  That's not what I'm saying.  I'm saying it can't be decided in a context-free way, thus it introduces ambiguity into the grammar, which was something the OP mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: @rmeador: ...and my point is that the problem is solvable, so it practically doesn't pose any "lexical difficulties". The answer on the question I linked to also mentions that C++ is going to "fix" this soon-ish. It's not a real problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [Erlang uses this symbol](http://www.erlang.org/documentation/doc-5.7.5/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html) as one of its representations for "not equal".

[Erlang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_%28programming_language%29) is a language with strong support for concurrency, originally designed within Ericsson and used for writing software for telephone exchanges, but now gaining significant popularity outside.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out [Fortress Introductory Slides](http://www.slideshare.net/alexmiller/project-fortress). Fortess uses =/= for checking inequality. I suppose you look for readability in languages. If that's the case then I can tell that Fortess code can be rendered into very neat looking TeX.

[Project Fortress Old Site](http://projectfortress.sun.com/Projects/Community) (moved to java.net)

Answer (score 0):

A [google code search](http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&lr=&q=+%3D%2F%3D+) for `=/=` doesn't turn up anything obvious, so I would say nothing mainstream.

There wouldn't be any issues with any operator you want, the computer would simply look for `=/=` instead of `!=` or `<>` or whatever your language uses.

There are some really weird languages out there like [BrainFuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) language ([link](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/bf/))

```
++++++++++[>+++++++>++++++++++>+++>+<<<<-]>++.>+.+++++++..+++.>++.    <<+++++++++++++++.>.+++.——.——–.>+.>.
```

That is code for "Hello World".

Comment: Actually by Google code search I figured out that Erlang has it. It has /= for not equal to, and =/= exactly not equal to.

Comment: Great, I'm glad the link I provided produced an answer... not sure the negative vote was necessary!

Answer (score 0):

1. None that I know of
2. Not much harder than any other operator like `+=`, `??`, etc.

However, it's very cumbersome to type such an operator. Even `!=` will be simpler.